# latent heat loss of water in pipe

Tags: water

What is the latent heat loss of water with 
a temperature of 5 degrees c in pipe with an outside air temperature of 0, -5 and -10? This is a 6" hdpe dr11 pipe exterior with no insulation.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What's the application? Is there wind? And do you really expect an accurate answer on a "Home Improvement" forum?

Comment: Hmm, is it homework question season again?

Comment: Are you trying to determine how to prevent your pipes from freezing?

Answer (score 1):

Latent heat is 80 kcal per Kg in all cases, and ends with a pipe frozen solid.

Total heat is 85 kcal per kg in all cases. Now, if the water is actually flowing, you have some other factors that you haven't told us about, (lenght, wind, etc.) as well as not telling us if the water is flowing or not. In general, uninsulated water pipes below freezing are not a great idea unless there is constant flow of warm water, and you don't mind losing the heat.